# XmlReader and InvalidCharacter

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xmlreader

I am using `SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader()` to Execute an SqlCommand with `FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS`

Now, there is a column which contains for xml invalid characters (like 0x1F). When I read now the result of the XmlReader with

```
using (var xmlReader = command.ExecuteXmlReader()) {
xmlReader.Read();
    while (xmlReader.ReadState != ReadState.EndOfFile) {
        try {
            sb.Append(xmlReader.ReadOuterXml());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.Error("Error in xmlReader.ReadOuterXml()", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the Exception "Invalid Character" at `xmlreader.ReadOuterXml()` when It read the Invalid Character.
Does anybody know a Workaround how I can solve this problem?

Comment: arguably, if `FOR XML` is returning something that is not valid xml, then the only "correct" way to fix this is to log a bug with MS and have it fixed at source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could surround your XML data with `<![CDATA[Data]]>`, like this

```
<SomeNode><![CDATA[0x1F]]></SomeNode>
```

OR you can use `XmlConvert` to Encode/Decode the XML data. Look here for mor info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35577sxd%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: But the problem is, that xmlReader.ReadOuterXml() returns the XML-Content and there is the problem. I have no access before that to the XML-Content.

Comment: @t.kehl: The link gives you an example for that, you cam use `sb.Append(XmlConvert.DecodeName(xmlReader.ReadOuterXml()));`

Comment: But the Exception occurs in xmlReader.ReadOuterXml()

Comment: Aha! Sorry, now i understand better. Maybe you could load the whole file into memory (a string variable) and then read from it or change the wrong character or add CDATA.

Comment: The Data are coming out of an SQL-Server Database with the Query-Extension 'FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS'

Comment: Try this approach, load the data into a stream, normalize it and then parse it. Look at this link: http://seattlesoftware.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/hexadecimal-value-0-is-an-invalid-character/